# Read string with $USER variable as text and resolve it

Tags: bash

I have some config-file. Config-file contains string: `LocalPath /media/$USER`

I read config-file in bash-script:

```
while read var value
do
    export "$var"="$value"
done < my-conf-file.conf
```

So, I can use `$LocalPath` in bash-script. It equals: `/media/$USER`, but I want to have: `/media/user1` (user1 is my user).

How I can implement it?

Comment: Why isn't your config file simply a Bash script that you source?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`read` does not expand variables from your config file.

You can verify that:

```
$ read username
$USER
$ echo $username
$USER
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31926346/7365127) on Stackoverflow gives a solution.
Change your script to this to make it expand variables:

```
while read var value
do
    export "$var"="$value"
done < <(envsubst < my-conf-file.conf)
```

Answer (score 1):

As Kyle Strand suggested in [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974257/read-string-with-user-variable-as-text-and-resolve-it#comment1562412_974257), the easiest solution is to make the config file a Bash script:

```
export LocalPath=/media/$USER
```

Then source it from your main script:

```
source my-conf-file.sh
```

Or if you have a bunch of variables, and don't want to type `export` for every one, make the config file like this:

```
set -a
LocalPath=/media/$USER
set +a
```