# Read command to read enviornment variable

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, environment-variables

I have an interactive script to perform a compare of a local directory and a remote directory. I want the user to be able to provide the name of the remote user, name of the remote server and the two paths (local and remote are expected to be the same) that the script should compare (e.g.: read -p "Path to directory to compare: " dir). Here's a snippet of the interactive portion of the script.

```
read -p "Specify path of directory to check: " path
read -p "Specify remote user: " user
read -p "Specify remote host: " host

ssh $user@$host "ls -l $path"
```

When executing the script, I pass in an environment variable $LAVAIP (set in .bashrc - export LAVAIP="192.168.1.69") which is the IP of the remote server. Snippet below show what happenes...

```
Specify path of directory to check: ~/bin
Specify remote user: lava
Specify remote host: $LAVAIP

ssh: Could not resolve hostname $lavaip: Name or service not known
```

What's going on here? It doesn't understand that the hostname should be interpreted as an environment variable and it also attempts to use the lower case version of the variable name.

Comment: You can use `ssh $user@$(eval echo $host) ... `, but this would cause a security risk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason<sup>1</sup> you're seeing lower case in the message

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname $lavaip: Name or service not known
```

as [noted by FedKad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1397704/read-command-to-read-enviornment-variable/1397715?noredirect=1#comment2420730_1397715) is that SSH is making the case conversion itself ex.:

```
$ user=lava; host=\$LAVAIP
$ echo $host
$LAVAIP
```

but

```
$ ssh $user@$host
ssh: Could not resolve hostname $lavaip: Name or service not known
```

Meanwhile the fact the it doesn't get expanded is expected - variable expansion doesn't occur on the `read` input line, and once the value is read it just becomes literal text. See for example

- [Read string with $USER variable as text and resolve it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974257/read-string-with-user-variable-as-text-and-resolve-it)

You could in fact do something similar to the accepted solution there, using `envsubst`:

```
$ export LAVAIP="192.168.1.69"

$ read -p "Specify remote user: " user
Specify remote user: lava
$ read -p "Specify remote host: " host
Specify remote host: $LAVAIP

$ echo "$(envsubst <<< "$user@$host")"
lava@192.168.1.69
```

Alternatively you could use *variable indirection*:

```
# "unexport" the variable - doesn't need to be in the environment for this option
$ export -n LAVAIP    

$ read -p "Specify remote user: " user
Specify remote user: lava
$ read -p "Specify remote host: " host
Specify remote host: LAVAIP

# note the lack of $ - just enter the variable's name

$ echo "$user@${!host}"
lava@192.168.1.69
```

---

<sup>1</sup> If however plain `echo $host` is returning a lower case value, that *could* happen if the `host` variable was declared with the `-l` attribute:

```
$ declare -l host
$ read -p "Specify remote host: " host
Specify remote host: $LAVAIP
$ echo $host
$lavaip
```

You can check with `declare -p`:

```
$ declare -p host
declare -l host="\$lavaip"
```

Comment: Note: The `ssh` command will convert any host name given in UPPER case to lower case when it displays the error message:  `ssh NONE` » `ssh: Could not resolve hostname none: Name or service not known`

Comment: @FedKad thanks - that's a much more plausible explanation, do you mind if I add it?

Comment: Please test it in your system and update your answer accordingly.

Comment: @FedKad thanks - done